# What does this mean: "unable to send message, socket is not open"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ldap

I'm trying to connect to my ldap server, but it seems to be failing in someway or form:

```
import csv
from ldap3 import Server, Connection, ALL, NTLM, SUBTREE
import pandas as pd


server = Server('cybertest02.ad.arb.ca.gov', get_info=ALL)
c = Connection(server, user='myusername', password='mypassword')

c.search(search_base = 'o=test',
         search_filter = '(objectClass=inetOrgPerson)',
         search_scope = SUBTREE,
         attributes = ['cn', 'givenName'])

total_entries += len(c.response)
for entry in c.response:
    print(entry['dn'], entry['attributes'])
```

Error on line 12: where attributes is, unable to send message, socket is not open

Comment: can you show the whole stack trace?

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting `c.bind()` before the `c.search()` and after the `Connection()` statements.

According to [LDAP3 Docs](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/), you must [`bind()`](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/bind.html) to establish a new authorization state in the server.

- As specified in RFC4511 the Bind operation is the “authenticate” operation.
- When you open a connection to an LDAP server you’re in an anonymous connection state. What this exactly means is defined by the server implementation, not by the protocol.
- The `bind()` method will open the connection if not already open.
- The Bind operation instead has nothing to do with the socket, but performs the user’s authentication.

Also you should use [`c.unbind()`](http://ldap3.readthedocs.io/unbind.html) to close the connection.

Comment: It the bind() return False it means that  credentials are wrong. You can check c.result to see details of the  error received from the server.